# Homebrew formulas for Golang

Tags: go, homebrew

I want to write a Homebrew formula for installing a Go package and its dependencies. Here's what I've got so far:

```
class LsGo < Formula
  desc "A more colorful, user-friendly implementation of `ls` written in Go"
  homepage "https://github.com/acarl005/ls-go"
  url "https://github.com/acarl005/ls-go/archive/v0.0.0.tar.gz"
  sha256 "db9ba7300fbbaf92926b2c95fd63e3e936739e359f123b5a45e6ca04b490af51"

  depends_on "go" => :build

  def install
    ENV["GOPATH"] = buildpath
    (buildpath/"src/github.com/acarl005").mkpath
    ln_s buildpath, buildpath/"src/github.com/acarl005/ls-go"
    system "cd", buildpath/"src/github.com/acarl005/ls-go"
    system "go", "get", "./"
    system "cd", "-"
    system "go", "build", "-o", bin/"ls-go"
  end

  test do
    system bin/"ls-go", "--help"
  end
end
```

But I get an error about running `go get ./` outside the `$GOPATH`.

```
==> cd /private/tmp/ls-go-20180612-22435-oidqms/ls-go-0.0.0/src/github.com/acarl005/ls-go
==> go get ./
Last 15 lines from /Users/andy/Library/Logs/Homebrew/ls-go/02.go:
2018-06-12 16:31:14 -0700

go
get
./

go get: no install location for directory /private/tmp/ls-go-20180612-22435-oidqms/ls-go-0.0.0 outside GOPATH
```

This doesn't make sense to me. I set `ENV["GOPATH"]` to `/private/tmp/ls-go-20180612-22435-oidqms/ls-go-0.0.0/`, and I cd'ed into a subdir of that path. Why is it saying I'm outside the `$GOPATH`?

How should I get the dependencies for my package?

EDIT: I'd prefer to avoid vendoring packages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that your Homebrew formula is just a Ruby class with some DSL magic to make it friendlier. That means that `system` runs commands in a separate process so this:

```
system "cd", "some_directory"
```

will change the current directory in a separate process and then that process exits without affecting the parent.

You should use [`Dir.chdir`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Dir.html#method-c-chdir) instead:

```
Dir.chdir buildpath/"src/github.com/acarl005/ls-go" do
  system "go", "get", "./"
end
system "go", "build", "-o", bin/"ls-go"
```

Using the block form (i.e. `Dir.chdir dir do ... end`) will change directives, run the `system` command, and then change back to the original directory before continuing so you don't have to worry about the `cd -` part.